# Laravel - caching external data in a model for a period of time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

One field in model is loaded from an external resource. Loading from an external resources may take a lot of time so i would like to do it as rarely as possible. Here is what i have so far:

```
class User extends Model {
  private $loaded = false;
  private $name = null;

  getName(){
    if(!$this->loaded){
      $this->name = loadNameFromExternalResource($this->id);
      $this->loaded = true;
    }
    return $this->name;
  }
}
```

This works well within a single request. I can call Auth::user()->getName() as many times as i want and only the first time will result in loading from an external resource.

But that's not enough, i would also like to avoid this loading in the next requests. So Im thinking that it would be good to cache this field for a limited amount of time, for example an hour. Then each request would get the value from cache and only one request per hour would have to load it from external resource.

But I cant quite figure out how to do this within a model. Because there may be different instances of User model for different users within the same request i can just store it in cache with a static key. The best i could think of was to store it with user id, like this:

```
class User extends Model {
  private $loaded = false;
  private $name = null;

  getName(){
    if(!$this->loaded){
      if(Cache::has('user_name_' . $this->id)){
        $this->name = Cache::get('user_name_' . $this->id);
      } else {
        $this->name = loadNameFromExternalResource($this->id);
        Cache::put('user_name_' . $this->id, $this->name, 60);
      }
      $this->loaded = true;
    }
    return $this->name;
  }
}
```

But this solution seems kind of strange to me. What do you guys think? Can it be done better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you presented using Cache facade is a typical solution:

- check if value is in cache
- if yes - return
- if not - load, store in cache, return

You just don't need that extra **loaded** flag - checking if value exists in cache should be enough.

Why do you see anything wrong with that?

Anyway, that code above can be greatly simplified if you use **remember** function of Cache facade:

```
private $name;
public function getName() {
  if (!$this->name) {
    $this->name = Cache::remember('user_name_' . $this->id, 60, function () {
      return loadNameFromExternalResource($this->id);
    });
  }
  return $this->name;
}
```

This will try to fetch a value from cache. If it exists, it will be returned. If not, the callback provided will be called and the value it returns stored in cache for 60 minutes.

See the docs for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache

Comment: I didnt like the 'user_name_' . $this->id part very much. I was hoping there was a class instance specific way to cache something.

Comment: No. You need to define cache key yourself.

Comment: But wont this solution access the underlying cache every time its called? For example if i use DB as cache and call getName() ten times in a row, it will result in 10 queries?

Comment: That's true. If you want to avoid multiple calls to cache as well, you'll need to somehow store a value in your model, like you did with that $isLoaded variable. See my updated answer.